# How to get test result from mocha

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

I have a test. I use wdio and mocha. And I want after test to get my test result (pass or fail) and save in some varible. How does I can do it? I red mocha documentation and find this https://mochajs.org/api/runnable but I always has undefined result. I can`t understand how I should use it?

```js
describe('some title', () => {
  it('some title', async () => {
    const runnable = new Runnable('some title', async () => {
      expect(await (await somePage1.someProp1).getText()).equal('some text 1');
      expect(await (await SomePage2.someProp2).getText()).equal('some text 2');
    });
    
    console.log(runnable.state);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mochawesome` for that. It's very efficient and outputs both JSON and styled elegant HTML reports.

You can install it globaly via npm

```
npm install -g mochawesome
```

And then run it

```
mocha --reporter mochawesome
```

More about `mochawesome` - https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome

Comment: I don`t need new reporter, i will use allure. I need to get my test-results value , and then use it  for testrail-integration